# How can i use correctly rest service in grails

Tags: rest, grails, spring-security

i am trying to create a grails app with scaffold and rest api, everything its ok with the scaffold but when i try to get information from the rest api i get some erros
my code:

```
package estudiolegal

import grails.plugin.springsecurity.annotation.Secured
import grails.rest.Resource

import static org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.*

@Resource(uri='/api/proyectos', formats=['json', 'xml'])
@Secured(['ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_ABOGADO','ROLE_CLIENTE'])
class ProyectoController {
    ProyectoService proyectoService

    static allowedMethods = [save: "POST", update: "PUT", delete: "DELETE"]
    def index = {
        redirect action: "list"
    }

    def create() {
        respond new Proyecto(params)
    }

    def save = {
        def proyecto = new Proyecto(params)
        proyecto.addToUsuarios(applicationContext.springSecurityService.currentUser)
        proyecto.save flush: true, failOnError: true
        redirect action: "show", id: proyecto.id
    }

    def edit(Long id) {
        respond proyectoService.get(id)
    }

    def update = {
        def proyecto = Proyecto.get(params.id)
        proyecto.properties = params
        proyecto.save flush: true, failOnError: true
        redirect action: "show", id: params.id
    }

    def show (Long id){
        respond proyectoService.get(id)
    }

    def list = {
        def proyectos = Proyecto.list()
        [proyectos: proyectos]
    }

    def delete = {

        def proyecto = Proyecto.get(params.id)
        proyecto.usuarios.each {
            if(it.proyectos.contains(proyecto))
            {
                it.removeFromProyectos(proyecto)
            }
        }
        proyecto.delete flush: true, failOnError: true
        redirect action: "index"
    }

    protected void notFound() {
        request.withFormat {
            form multipartForm {
                flash.message = message(code: 'default.not.found.message', args: [message(code: 'proceso.label', default: 'Proyecto'), params.id])
                redirect action: "index", method: "GET"
            }
            '*'{ render status: NOT_FOUND }
        }
    }

}
```

when i try to trigger this http://localhost:8080/api/proyectos whit  RestClient grails show the errors

2019-05-18 15:36:28.202 ERROR --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.g.web.errors.GrailsExceptionResolver   : MissingMethodException occurred when processing request: [GET] /api/proyectos
No signature of method: static estudiolegal.ProyectoController.count() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: print(java.io.PrintWriter), print(java.lang.Object), wait(), create(), edit(), list(). Stacktrace follows:

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsControllerClass$ReflectionInvoker.invoke(DefaultGrailsControllerClass.java:211)
    at org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsControllerClass.invoke(DefaultGrailsControllerClass.java:188)
    at org.grails.web.mapping.mvc.UrlMappingsInfoHandlerAdapter.handle(UrlMappingsInfoHandlerAdapter.groovy:90)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.RestLogoutFilter.doFilter(RestLogoutFilter.groovy:80)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsHttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsHttpPutFormContentFilter.groovy:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.RestTokenValidationFilter.processFilterChain(RestTokenValidationFilter.groovy:118)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.RestTokenValidationFilter.doFilter(RestTokenValidationFilter.groovy:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.groovy:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.RestAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RestAuthenticationFilter.groovy:143)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter.doFilter(MutableLogoutFilter.groovy:64)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.SecurityRequestHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityRequestHolderFilter.groovy:58)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
    at org.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:77)
    at org.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:67)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static estudiolegal.ProyectoController.count() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: print(java.io.PrintWriter), print(java.lang.Object), wait(), create(), edit(), list()
    at grails.rest.RestfulController.countResources(RestfulController.groovy:276)
    at grails.rest.RestfulController.index(RestfulController.groovy:62)
    at grails.gorm.transactions.GrailsTransactionTemplate$2.doInTransaction(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:94)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133)
    at grails.gorm.transactions.GrailsTransactionTemplate.execute(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:91)
    ... 38 common frames omitted

Comment: The code you showed there does not look like it corresponds to the error you have shown.  Are you sure those are in sync?

Comment: i dont know whats happend i am new in grails can you help me ?

Comment: Is not simpler to setup UrlMappings.groovy in Controller folder to link your controller to rest end point?